# How do I determine which DateTime format WCF is using when it calls DateTime.ParseExact?

Tags: wcf, datetime, serialization

My WCF service fails to deserialize an XML response. I get an error stating that 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

I see in the stack trace that the code fails on

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) +6364410
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.ToDate(String value) +58
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderINgiReportingMgmnt.Read50_TransactionItem_Type(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +629
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderINgiReportingMgmnt.Read105_transactionDetailRs() +1261
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer54.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) +43
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +579
```

How do I figure out which Datetime format WCF is using?  And how do I change the format?  I can't control what format I get the dates in.

PS: The date in the XML is "2010-01-03T11:59:59". This deserializes fine using a normal DateTime.Parse.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` is meant to be used when you already know the format of the input string, stick with `DateTime.Parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the exact format did not matter. The problem was that the wsdl (the xsd specifically) specified that the value is an xsd:date. But since the value had **time** as part of the string the deserializer threw an exception.

So the problem was with incorrect data. I asked that the XSD be changed.